# Array en Kotlin

Tags: java, array, bucle-for, kotlin, size

Tengo un par de consultas.

¿Porqué el algoritmo que adjunto dice: `arreglo.size -2` y no `arreglo.size-1`? O sea, ¿porqué la condición para salir del bucle for es tamaño menos 2?

Algoritmo completo en:

https://www.tutorialesprogramacionya.com/kotlinya/detalleconcepto.php?punto=21&codigo=21&inicio=15
**(Problema 3)**

```
for(i in 0..arreglo.size-2){

    if (arreglo[i+1] < arreglo[i])
    ordenado = false

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Lo que sucede es que estas realizando una comparación del elemento actual con el siguiente para determinar si los elementos no estan ordenados de menor a mayor, esto cuando el siguiente elemento es mayor:

```
...
if (arreglo[i+1] < arreglo[i]) {
...
```

Si usaras -1 ( `for(i in 0..arreglo.size-1) {`) , al final tratarías de obtener el elemento con indice 10 (9+1) en la lista el cual en realidad no existe y se provocaría un error:  ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
...
if (arreglo[9+1] < arreglo[9]) {
...
```